# Check if a form field is defined with a variable in the name

Tags: forms, dynamic, coldfusion

I have an interesting problem here...

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#form.countField#" index="i">
<cfif isdefined('form["semester#i#"]')>
  <cfquery name = "insertCourses" datasource="cas_evaluation">
  INSERT INTO courses (faculty, semester, course, students, hours, team_taught, first_time, ec_dl, online, course_revision )
  VALUES ( '#form.name#', '#form['semester#i#']#', '#form['course#i#']#', '#form['numstudents#i#']#', '#form['hours#i#']#', '#form['team#i#']#', '#form['firsttime#i#']#', '#form['ec_dl#i#']#', '#form['online#i#']#', '#form['revision#i#']#')
  </cfquery>
 </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Basically, I have some dynamic fields that can be added in or deleted. (These are rows of fields btw...) The way I have it coded...if the user deletes a row in the middle... ( they delete row 2 and rows 1 and 3 are left...) it causes problems because the loop is looking for it but it is not there obviously. So I tried checking to see if one of the fields were defined...but it doesn't like the syntax of the isdefined variable.. :(

any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't quite understand the question. So this isn't working?

```
<cfif isdefined('form["semester#i#"]')>
```

Use

```
<cfif structKeyExists(form, "semester#i#")>
```

cfparam and isDefined don't like the array style syntax. In your case you could also use:

```
<cfif isdefined('form.semester#i#')>
```

Personally it's not a style I like myself but it should work ok.

Comment: Sometimes this won't work - I'm currently trying to see if a checkbox is checked in my form. The value doesn't get passed if the box isn't checked, and when I try to do <cfif struckKeyExists(form, checkbox)> when the box isn't checked I get an error that the checkbox is undefined.

Comment: Wow, it’s been a long time since I thought about CF! I used to use cfparam to provision defaults to effectively set all the missing checkboxes to a default of false at the start before I began.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Form scope like a structure. If you use structKeyList(form), you will get a list of every form field defined.

Comment: can you give me an example? :)

Comment: This would loop over a form as a structure:

<cfloop item="key" collection="#form#">
  <cfoutput>The value of form.#key# is #form[key]#<br/></cfoutput>
</cfloop>

Answer (score 1):

Also, make sure you use cfqueryparam for escaping your sql variables. The code you have at the moment is full of sql injection holes. This code should work and should be safe.

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#form.countField#" index="i">
  <cfif structKeyExists(form, 'semester#i#')>
    <cfquery name = "insertCourses" datasource="cas_evaluation">
      INSERT INTO courses
        (faculty, semester, course, students, hours, team_taught, first_time, ec_dl, online, course_revision)
      VALUES
        ( <cfqueryparam cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' value='#form.name#' />
        , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' value='#form['semester#i#']#' />
        , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' value='#form['course#i#']#' />
        , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' value='#form['numstudents#i#']#' />
        , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' value='#form['hours#i#']#' />
        , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' value='#form['team#i#']#' />
        , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' value='#form['firsttime#i#']#' />
        , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' value='#form['ec_dl#i#']#' />
        , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' value='#form['online#i#']#' />
        , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' value='#form['revision#i#']#' />
        );
    </cfquery>
  </cfif>
</cfloop>
```